# how to create a shortcut to a folder in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, directory, shortcut, special-folders

Assume I have a folder called "C:\Program Files\Java" and a folder called "C:\Users\Public". I need to create a folder inside Public named "test". but If someone opens the folder test it should show the files inside "Java".

It is very similar to simple shortcut we create in windows. But i need to access it via command prompt or from a web-browser.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try http://geeknizer.com/create-symlink-in-windows/

Comment: Would be useful to paraphrase what's in that article. (And what's in that article is a software product)